# How would you create a standalone widget from this widget tree?

Tags: flutter

I have this widget tree representing a simple datapicker form Field:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => _showDataPicker(context),
  child: AbsorbPointer(
    absorbing: true,
    child: TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open),
            icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            hintText: "Password"),
        validator: (String value) {
          return null;
          if (value.isEmpty)
            return "Password can't be empty";
          else if (value.length < 8)
            return "Password must contain at least 8 chars";

          return null;
        }),
  ),
),
```

it is just a textformfield surrounded by an AbsorbPointer to disable input on it. From that code I would like to create a custom widget that I could insert in any other part of the widget tree. Something like this:

```
CustomFormDataPicker(
    validator: (value) {},
)
```

How would you do this? Would you inherit from FormField (because I want this to be used always in a form). Would you inherit from the top componenet GestureDetector and keep a reference to the TextFormField (Don't know how this would play with the parent Form)?

I'm a bit los here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't simply wrap the given tree in new subclass of [`StatelessWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) returning your `GestureDetector(...)` code in the overridden `build` method?

Comment: Just my ineptitude using flutter :). Pretty new to flutter. Just wanted to hear what more experienced would suggest.  I was not sure if extending from statefull widget was the most suitable thing here. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code. If you need further explanation don't hesitate, let me know.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: CustomFormDataPicker(
        validator: (String value) {
          // return null;
          if (value.isEmpty)
            return "Password can't be empty";
          else if (value.length < 8)
            return "Password must contain at least 8 chars";

          return null;
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}

typedef ShowDataPickerCallback = void Function(BuildContext context);

class CustomFormDataPicker extends StatelessWidget {
  final String Function(String message) validator;
  final ShowDataPickerCallback showDataPicker;

  CustomFormDataPicker({this.validator, this.showDataPicker});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => showDataPicker != null ? showDataPicker(context) : null,
      child: AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: true,
        child: TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open),
                icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                hintText: "Password"),
            validator: validator),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok that was one of the solutions I got. But not sure if extending from statefull widget was the best option here.

Comment: Using a `StatelessWidget` is more idiomatic in this case given that there is no changing, stateful data in the question. A stateless widget can be easily refactored to a `StatefulWidget` if needed.

Comment: I accepted the stateless edit suggested ,but actually it is not affecting the concept of the solution which is the functional side of Dart language,:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode you can use its shortcut called extract widget.